# Why am I getting wet?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I just finished building a wooden house with upgraded walls.  It started to rain outside and then a notification said I am wet.  Why is this ? The ceiling, walls, and flooring are all made of upgraded wooden frame.

Comment: Looks like [everything's coming up Milhouse!](http://i.imgur.com/jTbKKYu.gif)

Comment: Commented here because I don't know the answer for sure. I read that the character should be 5 blocks from an edge to be fully dry. That would mean you need a 10+1 length roof to remain 100% dry in the middle I think. This is the link I found it in: [gamepedia](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Game_mechanics#Player_Wetness)

Comment: I've had times where I'll get the "You are wet" message when I'm standing or walking under a wooden hatch to the outside. Apparently when you look up and see daylight, the game knows there are gaps, and that would cause any tile within 5 blocks of the hatch to still be in the "splash zone"... did you have a hatch above you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop getting wet, you must either be in a fully-enclosed room or at least 5 blocks away from a block that is getting wet. To start drying, your core temperature must be above 40°F.

If your room has a roof but is small and has an open door frame, that may be the cause.